# Ajax return code 400

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, javascript, errors

I've never used ajax in wordpress before and I'm trying to make a simple ajax request by following some video tutorials on youtube but it always return this error message: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

My javascript (inside my own template file):

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action: 'my_action'
                },

                success: function ( response ) {
                    console.log("success");
                    alert("success");   
                },
                error: function( error ){
                    console.log("error");
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

my functions.php file:

```
<?php



add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'insertEmail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'insertEmail');

function insertEmail(){
  echo "<script> alert('functions fil'); </script>"
  die();
}

?>
```

Comment: OT: Why are you trying to use ajax instead of the much better REST endpoints?

Comment: @kero I don't even know what REST endpoints is :) I'm in a little bit of time pressure so if it's something that's hard to implement into wordpress/learn I'm afraid I don't have the time to learn it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really have the time now to explain. From a first look: `<script>` tags don't belong in the output, it expects pure JavaScript

Comment: Have you set `ajaxurl`? It is only set by default on admin screens, not the front end.

Comment: @Milo I think it's set actually since if i go into the browser console and type in "ajaxurl" it outputs something like "www.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php". I haven't set it manually though.

Comment: @kero Yes, that's only there so that i can output an alert box to see if the php function runs. I don't think the ajax problem has to do with that.

Comment: For both actions, change `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'insertEmail');` to `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');`. That is what codex specifies should be done. Which means changing the handler function name to `my_action` from insertEmail. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base snippet I use for AJAX submits in Wordpress, it might help you out:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['my_theme_ajax_submit']))
    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'my_theme_ajax_submit' ) )
        my_theme_ajax_submit(); 

function my_theme_ajax_submit() {
    // do something
    // some php code that fires from AJAX click of #fire
    wp_mail( 'user@domain.com', 'my_theme_ajax_submit() fired', time());
    wp_die();
}
?>

<button id='fire'>Fire Something</button>

<script>
    jQuery('#fire').click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: { 
                "my_theme_ajax_submit": "now",
                "nonce" : "<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_theme_ajax_submit' ); ?>"
            },
            success: function(response) { 
                jQuery('#fire').text("Somthing Done!");
            },
            error: function(response) { 
                jQuery('#fire').text("...error!");
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

This can be built better - housing the scripts in [`wp_enque_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), having the `my_theme_ajax_submit()` condition check / firing at an early hook like [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) (instead of within a template), or using the proper [`wp_ajax_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) hooks (never seem to work for me) - but it should give an idea.

Comment: My page doesn't load for some reason if i write my php functions in the template file :/